# Redirect to same path on new domain

Tags: php, apache, redirect, dns

Hi I've got a new domain and want to redirect my users to the new domain's equivalent path.

So if they go on: oldsite.com/money.php?value=1

Then it should direct them to: newsite.com/money.php?value=1

I have the same header.php for all the pages, so can this be done with a simple php line?

Comment: You want to do that with a php script? I don't know where you have your domain but can't you set some setting to do that for you?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I will give you 2 functions which could be useful for some other thing;

```
function currentURL() {
     $pageURL = 'http';
     ($_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"] === 443) ? $pageURL .= "s" : '';
     $pageURL .= "://";
     if ($_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"] != "80") {
      $pageURL .= $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"].":".$_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"].$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
     } else {
      $pageURL .= $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"].$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
     }
     return $pageURL;
 }


function redirect2NewDomain () {
    $url = currentURL();
    if(filter_var($url, FILTER_VALIDATE_URL, FILTER_FLAG_HOST_REQUIRED) === FALSE) {
       return false;
    }
    # Get the url parts
    $parts = parse_url($url);
    Header( "Location : {$parts['scheme']}://{$parts['host']}" );
}
```

Ofcourse using .htaccess is much more easier and will be better for SEO;

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.newdomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

I hope this helps

Comment: I would definitely go with .htaccess method.

Comment: You can send a 301 header in the PHP script and it will have similar effects from an SEO perspective.

Comment: Yes, I could add that still it is not any better than .htaccess

Comment: Just found this post because I had the same problem, went with .htaccess method. Worked great!

Comment: Thanks so much for the info  .htaccess

Comment: The .htaccess is the Solution, Thanks!

Answer (score 11):

Something like this should work:

```
$uri = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
Header( "HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently" );
Header( "Location: http://newsite.com$uri" );
```

But if you can modify your web server's configuration instead, that would be a better place to do it.

Comment: `script_name` doesn't contains the get variables

Answer (score 8):

You shouldn't do this in PHP. These things can be easily done in your .htaccess:

```
#Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.olddomain.com$[OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^olddomain.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.newdomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

This code will redirect `olddomain.com/page.php` to `newdomain.com/page.php`

It will also redirect folders: `olddomain.com/folder/` to `newdomain.com/folder/`

By using this code google will also understand that you are switching domains and won't lower your page ranks for double content.

Answer (score 3):

I like to  use this code:

```
// BEGIN redirect domain
$domainRedirect = 'myNewDomain.com';
if(
($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] != $domainRedirect)
){
header("HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently");
header("Location: http://".$domainRedirect.$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
exit;
}
// END redirect domain
```

this:

```
header("HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently");
```

is optional but better for SEO: (https://moz.com/learn/seo/redirection)

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
$new_domain = "http://example.com"; //your new domain
$uri = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; // URL from the request with the get variables
header("Location: " . $new_domain . $uri);
```